# How are the values of fundamental C/C++ types physically stored?

Tags: c++, c, memory, binary-data

I am playing with state-space, which requires very effective storage of explored states. That means, I need to store multiple information in a variable that's as small as possible.

Let's have a very simple example: Imagine I'd like to store two coordinates. I can create a struct of two integers, but each integer is (correct me if I am wrong) 32b. But neither of my coordinates is greater than **15**. With zero, it is 16 = 2^4 distinct values, which means I only need 8b store both of them. So with some bitwise operator magic, I am able to store these two values inside a single `char`:

```
unsigned int x, y; // initialized!!!!!
char my_code = (x << 4) | y;
```

Of course, this code will work only, if `x` and `y` are stored in "straight-code" (**I am not sure about this name.** It is simple binary representation of number, from biggest bit 2^n to 2^1 )

So my question is: **which binary codes are used to store which fundamental C/C++ variables?**

**EDIT:** Premature optimalization? No. My current task is small and it is preparation for bigger problem, where I need to store 4 coordinates from 0 to 7. Thoose coordinates are positions on board 8x8. So I need to keep track of many many unique combinations - because state-space searching is based on generating new states, which weren't already explored.

There is no possible way of storing multiple ints and using custom comparator function and `set`. For big problems like this, my memory would bleed and keeping track of what I already visited wouldn't be nice either. Bitset with size of possible combinations is probably the best way. (You might say, that problem, that I described is too big for bitset that large, but there is neat trick to handle it, UNIMPORTANT for this question.) So, I need some sort of "hash", which can be created many ways - using modular arithmetics (one type of answers) or bitwise operations. Complexity between these two solutions aren't much different for todays computer to matter. Because I am curious, I wanted to use more exotic second way. But for that to work, I needed to know, how are numbers stored at binary level - if there is some verid coding, which would my idea make absolutely unusable.

My question wasn't about size of variables either - those are well documented.

Comment: Bitfields might be able to help with this.

Comment: C++ does not mandate any particular binary representation. In your case, you are developing for a particular system, so you need to know how it is stored on your system.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm also gives you sizes for variables. But others are correct, depends on how the system is storing the data.

Comment: @Borgleader: I'd actually prefer bitwise-operations to bitfields.

Comment: `isn't greater than 16` is not possible to store in 4 bits. interval [0,16] contains 17 values.

Comment: Integers can be as small as 8 bits.

Comment: _@RainbowTom_ _"this code will work only, if x and y are stored in "straight-code" (**I am not sure about this name.** "_ Are you actually worrying about endianess representation? That's completely transparent for binary operations.

Comment: So, I must look up, how machine, which will be executing my code, does this?

Comment: `uint8_t` and others

Comment: `char` is usually signed. it's better to use `unsigned char` in your case.

Comment: Are there more than 2 binary codes? `0`, `1` and ...?

Comment: @fukanchik: Whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-defined.

Comment: @EOF yep, this is what i am talking about - it's better to specify it explicitly.

Comment: You can store two values `a`, `b` as `n = 16 * a + b` and extract them as `a = n / 16` and `b = n % 16`. Then `n` will fit into an 8-bit type.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I have a feeling that would be slower than shifts.

Comment: @SergeyA: A good optimizing compiler will use shifts for multiplication/division by powers of two.

Comment: @Olaf: you [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583533/how-are-the-values-of-fundamental-c-c-types-physically-stored#comment60766169_36583533) 'Integers can be as small as 8 bits' — if you mean `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` as 'integers' then you're correct; if you mean `int` then the standard requires `int` to support a range ±32,767 which requires the type to be at least 16 bits (but it certainly doesn't have to be 32 bits, as the question suggests; that's 'normal' but far from mandated).

Comment: @fukanchik: I suspect on most implementations it actually is unsigned. Just counting ARM vs. x86. Not sure what they have for 8051 and other 8 bit MCUs.

Comment: @Olaf: I don't think either of those architectures mandates the signedness of `char`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I try to differentiate very precisely between `int` and integer. Of course you are right about `int`. And for most implementations, `int` has only 16 bits.

Comment: @Olaf JFYI: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d294k5z.aspx

Comment: @Olaf: The trouble is that you and I know the difference, but many people reading the comment chain won't appreciate the subtlety — so it is best to spell it out.

Comment: @EOF, division by 16 is fine. However, `n % 16` is much more instructions than `(n << 4) >> 4` (for 8-bit types)

Comment: @SergeyA: For `unsigned` types, `n % 16 == n & 15`. Ask your optimizing compiler of choice.

Comment: @fukanchik: Can you please provide an authoritative reference? And that is for a specific implementation, how is that relevant? It is a matter of the ABI for your platform which in terms is mandated often by the features of the CPU (which is the reason ARM defaults to unsigned, btw).

Comment: @EOF, I was playing with gcc. My mistake is that I didn't use unsigned int.

Comment: @EOF: AAPCS and the corresponding ABIs actually do very well. Simple reason is early ARM instruction set lacked a "load byte with sign extend" instruction, thus it would have required an additional instruction per load.

Comment: @Olaf that sounds more like a flame. What is not `authoritative` about that reference?

Comment: @fukanchik: This is about C, not a specific implementation. Thus the only authoritative (thanks for the correcting, if you ever write in my language, I hopefully can help, too) reference is ISO9899 or maybe a derived document.

Comment: You might be able to store your coordinates in a single byte.  But why?  What purpose does eeking out a few extra bits serve?  Just write your program in C or C++ or whatever language you choose, and don't worry too much about what the compiler is doing, until you have an actual speed issue or bottleneck to solve.  If you want more control, write your program in assembly code.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @DanKorn: There are more achitectures than PC or Mobile platforms. Actually most targets are still memory constrained. And OP clearly stated that he very well does have a bottleneck. There is a difference in code space and RAM/variable space. Recommending Assembler just to conserve RAM is nonsense.

Comment: @Olaf: No, unless such a statement was edited away, the OP never said he was dealing with a bottleneck; he just said that he was "playing with state-space."  He doesn't even mention exactly what problem he's trying to solve.  As for writing Assembler, if you don't like what the compiler is doing, how else are you going to optimize code specifically for all of the different architectures you mention?  I suppose you can play around with compiler flags and settings, but if you really care about memory storage to the bit level, you may need to be closer to the metal than what C can give you.

Comment: @DanKorn: " which requires very effective storage of explored states" - sound to me like he has or expects a bottleneck. It is not ours to judge he is correct or not. For this there is not enough information (I agree with you and think the question is either unclear or too broad). About Assembler: I don't see where OP has a problem with the generated code either. He just is unsure about the operations (a simple search or reading a C book would help a lot). One of the worst ideas is to "play around with compiler flags", as that expliots implementation defined behaviour or even UB - bad idea!

Comment: @DanKorn: And read my comment again! There is a clear difference betwee RAM efficiency (which you can control very well in C and is a matter of the ABI and code-efficiency which depends on the tool-chain.

Comment: I clarified my question. All the comments and answers here helped me some way, what I don't understand is, why I have 4 downvotes on this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Of course, this code will work only, if `x` and `y` are stored in "straight-code"

I'm guessing the term you're looking for is [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). However, regardless of the endianness of your system, `(x << 4) | y` gives you the same value. Math is **endian-agnostic**. Math is just math. The only difference is what the memory layout is - and for a single byte, even that doesn't matter.

We can work through an example. Let's say `x` is `0x0A0B0C0D` and `y` is `0x01020304`. If your system is big-endian, that means the memory layout is:

```
x            : 0A 0B 0C 0D
y            : 01 02 03 04
x << 4       : A0 B0 C0 D0
(x << 4) | y : A1 B2 C3 D4
to char      :          D4
```

If it was little-endian:

```
x            : 0D 0C 0B 0A
y            : 04 03 02 01
x << 4       : D0 C0 B0 A0
(x << 4) | y : D4 C3 B2 A1
to char      : D4
```

Either way, `0xD4`.

---

Although, one thing you do have to worry about is the actual conversion to `char`. From [conv.integral]:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source
>   integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). *[ Note:* In a two’s
>   complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there
>   is no truncation). *—end note ]*
>
> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type;
>   otherwise, the value is **implementation-defined**.

If `char` is unsigned, that part is well-defined. If it's signed, it's not. So prefer to use `unsigned char` for `my_code`.

Comment: Left shift can invoke UB. Thus no, it need not give the same value. Some of your examples actually do on typical 32 bit and larger machines. Not to mention machines with smaller `int`.

Comment: @Olaf Can you give an example where left shift on primitive data types can invoke UB?

Comment: @callyalater: Please read 6.5.7p4

Comment: Endianness is one thing, I was worried about, but I don't quite understand, how are numbers (values) coded into physicall memory and how much I can relly on it.

Comment: @RainbowTom there is nothing special: unsigned values are encoded as SUM{x_0_31}(x_i*2^i) what did you expect?

Comment: Something far worse, this is what I was looking for. In history, there were some verid codes, like BCD or other codes (which I can't find in any english sources).

Comment: So I can relly on, that every unsigned type will be stored like SUM{x_0_31}(x_i*2^i)?

Comment: @callyalater if you left shift a 32bit unsigned integer by 32 bits or more you get UB. That's just one example.

Comment: @Barry: 0x0A0B0C0D is either `int` (on I32) or `long` (on I16L32). (Silently ignoring exotic architectures). See 6.4.4.1p5

Comment: @Olaf `unsigned int x, y;`

Comment: @Barry: C11 draft standard n1570 *6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators 3 [...] If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @Barry No. That is not correct. As per the standard "The result is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the number of bits in the left expression’s type.".   Also, I dare you to try such a shift on a Power processor - Intel and Power use different number of bits (5 vs 6) to hold the result and what you end up with differs. In any case, for C++ it is undefined. You are simply wrong.

Comment: Yep, I was wrong. [expr.shift] is awkwardly worded in that the left-shift undefined behavior section only mentioned `signed E1`, where the unsigned UB bit is about both shifts.

Comment: @Barry: Ok, sorry, I did not notice you mean that in context of the question. Point taken.

Comment: Not sure what the other discussion is. 6.5.7p3 is about the **right** operand, i.e. the "shift count". A count of `4` is definitively smaller than the width of any integer type. Nevertheless, the conversion to `char` is implementation defined for `signed char`.

Comment: @Olaf Now *that* is something worth editing into the answer.

Comment: @RainbowTom: BCD and others like Gray-Code are still used. Especially the latter has quite some advantages in specific applications.

Comment: @Barry, you sum all that I needed to know. I was worried about BCD and Gray-Code. I am not good at hardware but it has its aplications, so I needed to be absolutelly sure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to hack things yourself. The compiler is perfectly capable of doing this directly:

```
struct Packed {
  unsigned x : 4;
  unsigned y : 4;
};
```

You'd better have a few million of those, else the saving isn't really worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

C does not mandate sizes for `short`, `int`, or `long`; it specifies the ranges of values they must be able to represent.  An `unsigned int` must be able to represent *at least* values in the range 0 to 65535, meaning it must be *at least* 16 bits wide, although it may (and often is) wider.  A signed `int` must represent *at least* the range -32767 to 32767.  Note that C does not mandate two's complement representation, which is why the lower value is -32767 and not -32768.

Also, these types may have *padding bits* in addition to value bits.  I've never worked on an implementation that used padding bits in integral types.

Integral values are stored in the value bits using regular binary representation (i.e., N bits, leftmost bit is the most significant bit).

C99 added the `stdint.h` header, which defines integer types that have exact widths and no padding bits.  If your values really do range from 0 to 15, then I'd suggest you use `uint8_t` (8 bits, unsigned) for each.  Since these types fit into a single byte, you won't have any endianness issues.

Comment: "C does not mandate sizes for ..." - you forgot `char`. And unsigned intgers have to use all bits (excluding padding), i.e. they always have a max. of `(1 << N) - 1`. FYI: `stdint.h` fixed-width types (`intN_t`) are also guaranteed 2s complement.

Answer (score 0):

C/C++ standards do not enforce particular representation for [integral types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)). Actually, the standards allow three different representations --  two's complement, ones's complement, and signed magnitude representation. Luckily, positive numbers look the same in all of the representations.

Anyway, you do not have to care about it -- simply avoid bit manipulation operators as follows. If the range of your coordinates is [0, N), you can pack them into a wider data type as:

```
code = N * x + y;
```

or

```
code = N * N * x + N * y + z;
```

For N = 16, you can pack two coordinates into a single `unsigned char` as:

```
unsigned char code = 16*x + y;
```

Comment: With the latter two representation a problem arises with the two `0` (`+0` and `-0`), as the standard has some requirements here. Anyway, for a custom data format, any encoding can be used, including fractional, RLE, etc. And using bit-operations is actually the common way to assemble/disassemble custom encodings. You don't even explain why **you think** they are to be avoided.

Comment: @Olaf: It is not necessary to avoid them. However, the bit manipulation operators are only useful if N is a power of two.

Comment: `>>` and `<<` are **not** "bit manipulation" operators. They are *arithmetic* operators that, to the extent that they are defined by the standard, are guaranteed to have the same effect on *numerical values* on all platforms, having absolutely nothing to do with the underlying representation. (There are undefined cases whose differences may become visible if a system chooses to implement them in a bit-shifting way. This means nothing.)

Comment: @Leushenko: The same answer is also true in this case. The `<<` and `>>` operators are only useful in conjunction with powers of two.

Comment: @Leushenko: They are _bitwise shift operators_. I'd be careful about the "arithmetic", because that would imply e.g. preserving the sign at least for right shift of a signed integer. The standard intentionally leaves this to the implementation (not sure why they made left shift  through the sign UB). This is also the reason they do **not** have the same effect on a ll platforms for **all** numerical (you mean integer, bitshifts are neither defined for floating point/complex nor fractional types) values.

Comment: @DaBler: Reading the question, I think this restriction is well given as for most applications.

Comment: @Olaf: In addition, my approach also works with negative coordinates, say in the range [-N/2, N/2). Note that decoding is done with `%` operator and adding a correction. In contrast, the usage of bit-operations results in additional treatments in encoding as well as decoding (dependent on the underlying binary representation).

Comment: @DaBler: Negative values are a special problem, I'd have to check if that really works, especially when decoding. As I prefer the common approach, not only for clarity, but also because of speed (division is more expensive than bitshift on all existing architectures, sign-extension will very likely not eat that up). Note that a good compiler might use bitfield instructions to encode/decode if you use a know pattern. I'll leave it here; feel free to use your approach.